# Camel: Exchange fails when 2 recipientList steps called

Tags: java, xslt, apache-camel

I'm trying to call 2 xsl transforms in my route via recipientList. I have one wrapped in a choice step, and the other added as normal:

```
    from("direct:cosTransform")
    .routeId(TransformerConstants.TRANSFORM_XSLT_ROUTE)
    .process(exchange -> {

        // Get the xml payload from the exchange body
        final String xml = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

        // Determine LOB and set as header.  If the LOB is invalid, the xslt step will fail.
        final String lob = TransformerUtil.getLOBFromAcordXml(xml);
        if (null == lob) {
            throw new GeneralException("Could not derive the LOB from the ACORD Form.  ACORD Form["
                    + TransformerUtil.getAcordFormFromAcordXml(xml) + "]");
        }
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("lineOfBusiness", lob);

        // Market should be NI or BI.  If the market is invalid, the xslt step will fail.
        final String market = TransformerUtil.getMarketFromAccordXml(xml);
        if (!StringUtils.equals(market, TransformerConstants.BI_MARKET)
                && !StringUtils.equals(market, TransformerConstants.NI_MARKET)) {
            throw new GeneralException("Missing or invalid market[" + market + "].");
        }
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("market", market);
    })
    .log("Executing an xsl transform for Market=${header.market} and LOB=${header.lineOfBusiness}")
    .choice()
    .when(header("market").isEqualTo("NI"))
        .recipientList(simple("xslt:./xsl/${header.market}/Common.xsl?saxon=true&contentCache=false")).id("commonTransformNI")
        .log("after common :${body}")
    .endChoice()
    .recipientList(simple("xslt:./xsl/${header.market}/${header.lineOfBusiness}.xsl?saxon=true&contentCache=false"))
    .log("after lob : ${body}")
    .choice().id("postTransform")
        .when(header("market").isEqualTo("NI"))
            .process(exchange  -> {
                String xml = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

                xml = TransformerUtil.setUniqueIds(xml);
                exchange.getIn().setBody(xml);
            })
        .endChoice()
    .end();
}
```

`

When the exchange with a header of  to be transformed hits the first recipientList call(Common.xsl), the xml is transformed and it works fine. When it hits the second call, I get the following in the console:

```
[ #0 - seda://transform-receive] [CLM] [CID=UNKNOWN] o.a.c.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.doStart DEBUG Starting producer: Producer[xslt://./xsl/NI/CGL.xsl?contentCache=false&saxon=true]
[ #0 - seda://transform-receive] [CLM] [CID=UNKNOWN] o.a.camel.impl.ProducerCache  .doGetProducer DEBUG Adding to producer cache with key: Endpoint[xslt://./xsl/NI/CGL.xsl?contentCache=false&saxon=true] for producer: Producer[xslt://./xsl/NI/CGL.xsl?contentCache=false&saxon=true]
[ #0 - seda://transform-receive] [CLM] [CID=UNKNOWN] o.a.c.b.xml.XsltUriResolver   .resolve DEBUG Resolving URI from classpath:: classpath:./xsl/NI/CGL.xsl
[ #0 - seda://transform-receive] [CLM] [CID=UNKNOWN] o.a.c.p.DefaultErrorHandler   .log DEBUG Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-LIBP03P-QK70A9V-60563-1487254928941-1-7 on ExchangeId: ID-LIBP03P-QK70A9V-60563-1487254928941-1-8). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ #0 - seda://transform-receive] [CLM] [CID=UNKNOWN] TRANSFORM.COR.XSLT.ROUTE      .log ERROR null
[ #0 - seda://transform-receive] [CLM] [CID=UNKNOWN] o.a.c.processor.SendProcessor .process DEBUG >>>> Endpoint[log://showException=true] Exchange[ID-LIBP03P-QK70A9V-60563-1487254928941-1-8]
```

I've tried a few tests, adding in a mock endpoint after the second call and checking for a message, using log messages to track how far along the route the exchange gets to and it never seems to make it to the second call, it always throws an exception when heading to the second xslt step. Even when I send in an exchange that won't match the when condition, it doesn't hit the second xslt step either. The paths in the xsl strings are correct, when i remove the choice logic and second xslt step, the xsl runs fine, whether the string is for the common.xsl file or a line of business xsl file

Note: Due to certain templates in the xsl, I have to split the transforms out into their own steps, i.e. i can't import one of the files in, so the transforms have to be called separately

EDIT: I have implemented a processor to run the xslt manually for now. I'd still like to get to the bottom of this though, even when using a .to call and hardcoding the parameters I still get the same issue. Is it something around the XSLT component in camel?

Comment: What is the output of your log-calls? E.g. what does your body look like immediately after the xslt within the choice? Also add a log immediately before the second xslt-call but after endChoice to see what the body looks like then.

Comment: the after common log shows the transformed xml, the after lob call doesn't fire, instead camel logs `Error NULL` and then log the body which is identical to the after common log.. I'll add another call in after end choice and update.EDIT: i logged after endChoice, and the body is identical to what is logged in after common

Comment: Add a log for body and one for each of the header immediately before the second xslt-call to see what the exchange looks like after the choice

Comment: Both headers look fine. market header is NI and lineOfBusiness header is CGL, which is how they should look. Body xml looks identical to previous body log. to make sure the path are right i removed the whole choice and used the xsl string that uses btoh headers, and the tests run fine. I swapped that out for the common xsl string and it also runs fine, its just whenever the choice is added back in that I get errors

Comment: I'm not used to the Java DSL but if the indentation matters then it looks to me as if you are applying the endChoice on the choice (perfectly logical). But reading up on it the endChoice seems as if it should go on the recipientList in order for it to return to the scope of the choice, if that makes any sense? http://camel.apache.org/why-can-i-not-use-when-or-otherwise-in-a-java-camel-route.html

Comment: tried movign the endChoice around, still getting the same issues.